# Python Html table can't find data when running on server

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi my code won't work when actually running online, it returns `None` when i use `Find` how can i fix this?

This is my code;

```
import time
import sys

import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

print "Initializing Python Script"

print "The passed arguments are "
urls = ["http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/355474/gigabyte-gv-n78toc-3g/specificaties/", "http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/328943/sapphire-radeon-hd-7950-3gb-gddr5-with-boosts/specificaties/", "https://www.alternate.nl/GIGABYTE/GV-N78TOC-3GD-grafische-kaart/html/product/1115798", "http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/320116/raspberry-pi-model-b-(512mb)/specificaties/"]
i =0
regex = '<title>(.+?)</title>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
word = "tweakers"
alternate = "alternate"
while i<len(urls):

  dataraw = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
  data = dataraw.read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
  table = soup.find("table", {"class" : "spec-detail"})
  print table
  i+=1
```

Here is the outcome:

```
Initializing Python Script
The passed arguments are 
None
None
None
None


Script finalized
```

i have tried using findAll and other methods.. But i don't seem to understand why it is working on my Command line but not on the server itself... 
Any help?

Edit

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_script.py", line 35, in 
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), 'html.parser')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suspecting you are experiencing the [differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

Specifying the parser explicitly works for me:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ["http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/355474/gigabyte-gv-n78toc-3g/specificaties/",
        "http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/328943/sapphire-radeon-hd-7950-3gb-gddr5-with-boosts/specificaties/",
        "https://www.alternate.nl/GIGABYTE/GV-N78TOC-3GD-grafische-kaart/html/product/1115798",
        "http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/320116/raspberry-pi-model-b-(512mb)/specificaties/"]

for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "spec-detail"})
    print table
```

In this case, I'm using `html.parser`, but you can play around and specify `lxml` or `html5lib`, for example.

Note that the third url doesn't contain a `table` with `class="spec-detail"` and, therefore, it prints `None` for it.

I've also introduced few improvements:

- removed unused imports
- replaced a while loop with indexing with a nice for loop
- removed unrelated code
- replaced `urllib` with `urllib2`

---

You can also use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module and set appropriate `User-Agent` header pretending to be a real browser:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls = ["http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/355474/gigabyte-gv-n78toc-3g/specificaties/",
        "http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/328943/sapphire-radeon-hd-7950-3gb-gddr5-with-boosts/specificaties/",
        "https://www.alternate.nl/GIGABYTE/GV-N78TOC-3GD-grafische-kaart/html/product/1115798",
        "http://tweakers.net/pricewatch/320116/raspberry-pi-model-b-(512mb)/specificaties/"]

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36'}
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "spec-detail"})
    print table
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @user3671459 and you are using the same list of URLs as I'm using in the answer?

Comment: @user3671459 I guess you've hit the site to often and they banned your IP address. The same exact code works for me.

Comment: @user3671459 I've added an alternative `requests` based solution with setting `User-Agent` - try if it helps with 403. If it doesn't work either - wait for some time and try to run the code again - they might ban you temporarily. And think about adding a delay between the requests.

Comment: i guess it must be a ban yes because tweaking your code to a DIV and other website does return me the data i need! Thank you =)!